# Why is Optional("Text") - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, option-type, optional-values

I just started with Swift. So I created a simple application with a label, button and a text field. When you click the button, the app has to change the label with the text of the text field.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func updateButton(sender: UIButton) {
        textLabel.text = "Hi \(textField.text) "
    }
```

The result is

> Hi Optional("TextOfTextField")

Okay. So it's a very simple question.

I hope someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: "Okey.. so its a very simple question" But what _is_ the question?

Comment: Why does it show 'Output("blabla")'. I only wanna show the string not something else with output.

Comment: It doesn't show "Output" anything.

Comment: Read the [Swift Optional documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) to learn more about them. By the way, Optionals are a central point of the Swift language.

Answer (score 14):

The text of your textField ***is*** an optional value because a text field can sometimes be empty. So, use an `if let` to unwrap the variable ***and*** make sure it's not nil — otherwise your program could crash:

```
if let text: String = textField.text {
   textLabel.text = text
}
```

Comment: When it's empty it's not nil. It's "".

Answer (score 12):

So the problem here is that the textField's text is an optional, that you have to unwrap for using it.

Just add an `!` to `textField.text` like this:

```
textLabel.text = "Hi \(textField.text!)"
```

Your output will now be `Hi TextOfTextField`

---

You have a few safer options to unwrap your optionals:

1. nil coalescing operator: `??`
   This will use either `textField.text`, or, if that's nil, use the other value provided, `"?"` in this case

   ```
   textLabel.text = "Hi \(textField.text ?? "?")"
   ```
2. `if let` statement:
   Note that this will only update your text field's text, if it's not nil. You could provide an `else` statement to deal with that.

   ```
   if let text = textField.text {
       textField.text = "Hi \(text)"
   }
   ```
3. `guard let` statement:
   This works similarly like the `if let` statement, except that your function will end after the statement.

   ```
   guard let text = textField.text else { return }
   textField.text = "Hi \(text)"
   ```

---

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This solution will only work when the text field contains text. When the text field is empty, the app will crash because it's trying to force-unwap a nil value.

Comment: @Henry: ElmerCat is correct. It *can* crash if your optional is `nil`, but if you're sure it's not, then you can safely force unwrap it like shown above. Otherwise, use ElmerCat's solution.

Comment: @Lin So I'm guessing that would be when the text label doesn't exist at all then? Since when it is just empty, it just returns an empty string, which doesn't cause a crash.

Comment: It'd happen if either the text field itself or its `.text` property `nil` is. That doesn't apply to an empty text field, cause as you said, it'd return `""`

Comment: In text fields it won't crash, since UITextField objects won't return a nil text by default, but someone on the future can assign nil to it to empty it, then your app will crash. This approach is hazardous and people coming here looking for the label formatting can crash they app if the string come elsewhere than a textfield

Comment: @RodolfoAntonici Added other ways to unwrap optionals, although it's pretty redundant.

Answer (score 1):

One more way can be to use Guard to check if it is not nil.

```
guard let nameText = textField.text else {
    print("break if nil")
    return
}
textLabel.text = "Hi \(nameText!)"
```

Using guard makes sure your app fails early if the condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for Swift 4.x, I unwrapped by using below command for option Int? values or Optional list cont:

```
\(topics?.count ?? 0 )
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Using (if let) or (guard let) you can unwrap the value**

```
if let text = textField.text {
    textField.text = "Hi \(text)"
}

guard let text = textField.text else { return }
textField.text = "Hi \(text)"
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem with this for **Swift 3**;

```
self.label.text = "\(transaction.amount!)"
```

Comment: Same solution as the one by LinusGeffarth from 2015... and this isn't even the best one, far from it.