# Swift 4 - optional word in string

Tags: swift, option-type

I have searched this site and found similar answers but for some reason I still get Optional word printed, here's my code:

```
if description != nil {
    description = description! + symbol + String(describing: accumulator)
    if let desc = description {
        print(desc)
    } else {
        description = String(describing: accumulator) + symbol
        if let desc = description {
            print(desc)
        }
    }
}
```

The output is: Optional(value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Optional("Text") - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986284/why-is-optionaltext-swift)

Comment: Please update your question with the declaration of `accumulator` and `symbol`.

Comment: Most of your code needs to be rewritten. Posting those declarations will allow someone to show you the proper way to write that code.

Comment: that's a lot of code there, below answer is correct

Comment: I agree with rmaddy, that is *not* a lot of code, at least not a lot of relevant code. Also, you should not just focus on the quick fix but improving your code in general, @KirillC.

Comment: @KirillC What's a lot of code? I asked you to post 2 additional lines showing how `accumulator` and `symbol` are declared. With those meager additions to your question, someone can show you the proper way to rewrite your posted code in a much better way.

Comment: accumulator is declared as optional? and symbol is part of another function where it is an input in the function

Comment: so I just force unwrapped accumulator! not symbol and it worked

Comment: @KirillC Don't do that. Do not force-unwrap optionals. They are optional for a reason which means if they are actually nil, the app will crash.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that, I'm checking if accumulator isn't nil in a different function (before it gets to the code in question). But thanks for explaining, next time I'll make sure to enter better description.

Comment: @KirillC `if let description = description {` and use description inside the closure. This will unwrap the optional while preserving the original name. And never use `String(describing:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String(describing: s)` will output `"Optional()"` if the type of `s` is `String?`

So, you need to unwrap `accumulator` as well as `description`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var accumulator: String? = ""
var GlobalAccmulator:String = "NA"

if accumulator != nil
{
    GlobalAccmulator = accumulator!
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?