# Swift: Why do I get the error: "Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int' ", in my function:

Tags: swift

have this swift Code:

```
let from = newDate
let now = NSDate()
let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth])
let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: from, to: now as Date)

if difference.second <= 0{
    cell.DateLbl.text = "now"
}
```

my Problem is, that I get the following error and I don't really now how to solve it.

> Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and
>   'Int'

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: It's because `difference.second` is an optional and has the potential to be `nil`.

Comment: Don't use Foundation data types when they have native Swift alternatives. Use `Date` instead of `NSDate`.

Comment: @faridorid You have not accepted an answer for any of your questions. You should go through your six questions with an answer and if there is an answer that best solved your question, you should accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. Accepting an answer lets people know that your question has been solved. It also improves your reputation and earns you more privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare optional values (other than with `==`).

As written, `difference.second` is of type `Int?` (an optional `Int`).

The `second` property of `DateComponents` is optional. But since you specifically requested the `.second` component, it won't be `nil` in this usage so it is safe to force-unwrap it.

```
if difference.second! <= 0 {
```

Comment: I have another question. It gives me out: "Optional(4)m" instead of "4m", why did that happen

Comment: There is no code in your question that gives any output like that so you are now asking about another issue. You should close off this question by accepting the answer that best solved your original issue. If you have another issue you should post a new question with all relevant details and code.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33986284/3397217) and its answers. @faridorid

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `Int` and `Int?` are not the same type.  You need to handle cases where `difference.second` is `nil`.

One way to do this would be to use a nil-coalescing operator to treat `nil` as if it was zero.  So you could say `if (difference.second ?? 0) <= 0 {...`

Comment: I have another question. It gives me out: "Optional(4)m" instead of "4m", why did that happen

Comment: In this case the nil-coalescing operator is nonsensical. Since the `second` component is clearly specified the corresponding `second` property has always a value.

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve it

Comment: @vadian I get your point, though it's maybe a bit overkill to call a nil-coalescing option nonsensical.  It's 100% valid code.

Comment: Ok, replace nonsensical with inefficient. The operator is redundant because it will never evaluate to `false`.